# AST eclipse, method call with arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to add below code using ASTRewrite in java file. **where name is a variable**

printName(name);

I am trying below code for this

```
 MethodInvocation newInvocation = ast.newMethodInvocation();
 SimpleName methodAdd = ast.newSimpleName("printName");
 newInvocation.setName(methodAdd);
 Statement newStatement = ast.newExpressionStatement(newInvocation);
 listRewrite = rewriter.getListRewrite(block,Block.STATEMENTS_PROPERTY);
 listRewrite.insertFirst(newStatement, null);
```

output of this code is

```
 printName();
```

Can anyone help, how to add argument in method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `Name` to the [arguments List](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/MethodInvocation.html#arguments%28%29) of the MethodInvocation.

```
newInvocation.arguments().add(ast.newSimpleName("name"));
```